# How to integrate DateFormat in Android?

Tags: android, date-format

Currently I am Using `DateFormat` to convert **Current Date**, then I get the output like `8/27/12 (month/day/year)`.
But I want to display like this `Today, Yesterday`.
How to make this?
Please help me

I tried this:

```
long dtMili = System.currentTimeMillis();        
Date d = new Date(dtMili);  
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());    
System.out.println("DATE FORMAT  "+ dateFormat.format(d));
```

Using Dateformat in iPhone:

```
NSString *dateString = [self getNaturalDay:CurrentDate];
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Actually i want like this for how many members are message to day and yesterday so that

Comment: But i tried to convert only 8/27/12 (month/day/year) this way

Comment: I don't think so that there is any method to change date like your requirement without using your own logic. You can create some methods which will calculate dates for today, tomorrow, yesterday etc.. and then you can pass that date to your message calculator method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you:

Edit:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    long dtMili = System.currentTimeMillis();
    CharSequence d =DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(dtMili);
    Toast.makeText(this, d, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   }
```

Try to run this code. It will display "0 minutes ago",Instead of displaying some date format and depending upon ur logic it will display the time in its realtive form(i.e. 12 hours ago, yesterday, 3 days ago e.t.c.). This way of displaying time is called Relative time display.

Deadlock

Comment: @Minu just pass the time value(i.e long) u getting in this line of code and set the above value as final value and display it.

Comment: Can u please give simple exampl for this, becoz i didn'y understand.

Comment: @Minu If my solution is what, that you were looking for then pls accept this as an answer. So that it may help someone else facing the same issue.

Comment: Thank you, this comes like 0 second ago, but i want today, yesterday .

Comment: It will surely show the time as today,yesterday. Its showing o sec ago is bcoz i have used system.currentMilliSeconds(); which giving the current system time(Just to give u an example).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15848/discussion-between-deadlock-and-minu)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you compare dates and make a string to show in your page. else below is some reference for you

See this question/answers[How to get date in Today, Yesterday format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462064/right-way-to-format-date-with-strings-like-today-yesterday-tomorrow-etc)

as par suggestion in that answer, you should use [this library](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/)