# Best way to format a date relative to now on Android

Tags: android, string, date

I am creating a feature in an Android app to get an arbitrary date (past, present or future) and find the difference relative to now.

Both my `now` and `due` variables are `longs`, and this is my code:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
long due = now + 864000;

Log.d("Time in 1 day", DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(due,now, DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS));
```

I want the output to be something like `yesterday`, `today`, `in 4 days` or `19/12/2012`. However, the current output returns `in 0 days`...

I **don't** want the time to appear on these date strings.

What am I doing wrong and is the best method for formatting dates on Android?

Answer (score 34):

What I have in mind is changing:

`DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(due, now, 0L, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);`

Since the documentation says it returns the time relative to now.

If that fails use some of the brilliant libraries:

[Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

[PrettyTime](http://github.com/ocpsoft/prettytime)

[TimeAgo](http://github.com/kevinsawicki/java-timeago)

Comment: This won't work if I need diff in days! For ex. "14 days ago" not "2 weeks ago"

Comment: @oleynikd use DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS instead of 0L

Answer (score 9):

Finally I have implemented what you wanted..!

First you need to download [Joda Time from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/2.2/)

Extract it to any folder and put **joda-time-2.2.jar** into androidProject/libs folder.

**MainActivity**

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;
import org.joda.time.Months;
import org.joda.time.MutableDateTime;
import org.joda.time.Weeks;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;


public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
  private int day ;
  private int month ;
  private int year ;
  private int hour ;
  private int minute ;
  private long selectedTimeInMillis;
  private long currentTimeInMillis;
  private String strDay ="";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    year = 2013;
    month = 8;
    day = 10;
    hour = 15;
    minute = 28;

    DateTime selectedTime = new DateTime(year,month,day,hour,minute);
    selectedTimeInMillis = selectedTime.getMillis();

    MutableDateTime epoch = new MutableDateTime();
    epoch.setDate(selectedTimeInMillis); //Set to Epoch time

    DateTime now = new DateTime();

    currentTimeInMillis = now.getMillis();

    int days = Days.daysBetween(epoch, now).getDays();
    int weeks = Weeks.weeksBetween(epoch, now).getWeeks();
    int months = Months.monthsBetween(epoch, now).getMonths();

    Log.v("days since epoch: ",""+days);
    Log.v("weeks since epoch: ",""+weeks);
    Log.v("months since epoch: ",""+months);


    if(selectedTimeInMillis < currentTimeInMillis) //Past 
    {       
        long yesterdayTimeInMillis = currentTimeInMillis - 86400000;

        DateTime today = new DateTime(currentTimeInMillis);
        int year = today.getDayOfYear();
        int intToday = today.getDayOfMonth();
        DateTime yesterday = new DateTime(yesterdayTimeInMillis);
        int intYesterday = yesterday.getDayOfMonth();
        DateTime selectedDay = new DateTime(selectedTimeInMillis);
        int intselectedDay = selectedDay.getDayOfMonth();
        int intselectedYear = selectedDay.getDayOfYear();

        if(intToday == intselectedDay & year == intselectedYear)
        {
            strDay = "today";
        }
        else if(intYesterday == intselectedDay)
        {
            strDay = "yesterday";
        }
        else
        {
            strDay = "before "+ days +" days from today";
        }


    }
    else if(selectedTimeInMillis > currentTimeInMillis) //Future
    {
        long tomorrowTimeInMillis = currentTimeInMillis + 86400000;

        DateTime tomorrow = new DateTime(tomorrowTimeInMillis);
        int intTomorrow = tomorrow.getDayOfMonth();
        DateTime today = new DateTime(selectedTimeInMillis);
        int intToday = today.getDayOfMonth();

        if(intToday == intTomorrow)
        {
            strDay = "tomorrow";
        }
        else
        {
            days = -days;
            strDay = "after "+ days +" days from today";
        }


    }

    Log.v("strDay: ",""+strDay);
  }
}
```

You just need to change the value of day and you will get the desire output.
Currently I have given date 10 as input so output will be today.

I have set **date/day = 10** , **month = 8** , **year = 2013** , **hour = 15** , **min = 28**

**For past dates:**

```
input day 9 output yesterday

input day 3 output before 7 days from today

input year 2012 and day 10 output before 365 days from today
```

**For future dates:**

```
input day 11 output tomorrow

input day 27 output after 17 days from today

input day 23 and year 2016 output after 1109 days from today
```

Comment: Prettytime lib is also very human readble time format  http://www.londatiga.net/it/programming/android/how-to-convert-time-in-millisecond-into-relative-time-format-in-android/

Comment: oh I was searching for this,now I tested this approach and working like a charm Guys! Thanks man

Comment: how to get hours and mins difference from this method? Can we get the past/future hours,minutes etc?

Comment: @naveed ahmad yes dude u can extract hours and minutes from Milli seconds..and than u can get difference..:)

Answer (score 4):

> Best way to format a date relative to now on Android

I suggest you to use [`JodaTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

It's lightweight handy library and i think actually the best tool for working with Date instances.

And you can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179644/how-to-calculate-elapsed-time-from-now-with-joda-time).

Comment: A 500kb library for something simple as this? Unless my app is really dependant on dates (e.g. a calendar app), I would stick to using `DateUtils`, which is embedded in the OS.

Comment: @WordPressDeveloper JodaTime is actually best but i respect your opinion.

Comment: I agree with @hasMobi-AndroidApps There is no such thing as "best" library. It's all about tradeoffs.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just check for `yesterday` and `tomorrow` to avoid the `in 0 days`/`0 days ago` bug and leave `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString` handle the remaining cases?

```
String relative = null;

if(now < due && (due-now)<864000){
    relative = "tomorrow";
}else if(now > due && (now-due)<864000){
    relative = "yesterday";
}else{
    relative = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(due, now, DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS); // e.g. "in 4 days"
}

Log.d("result", relative);
```

Edit: You may also add `today` with a simple check as well.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work right if the time is more than a few weeks ago. The function returns the month and date instead (e.g. February 2).

Comment: This doesn't accommodate localization, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

**build.gradle**

```
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.9'
```

**Utils.java**

```
private static SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    private static SimpleDateFormat TIME_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat(" 'at' h:mm aa");
    public static String getRelativeDateTimeString(Calendar startDateCalendar) {
        if (startDateCalendar == null) return null;

        DateTime startDate = new DateTime(startDateCalendar.getTimeInMillis());
        DateTime today = new DateTime();
        int days = Days.daysBetween(today.withTimeAtStartOfDay(), startDate.withTimeAtStartOfDay()).getDays();

        String date;
        switch (days) {
            case -1: date = "Yesterday"; break;
            case 0: date = "Today"; break;
            case 1: date = "Tomorrow"; break;
            default: date = DATE_FORMAT.format(startDateCalendar.getTime()); break;
        }
        String time = TIME_FORMAT.format(startDateCalendar.getTime());
        return date + time;
    }
```

**Output**

```
Yesterday at 9:52 AM
Today at 9:52 AM
Tomorrow at 9:52 AM
Sep 05, 2017 at 9:52 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual reason is the number 864000 is in miliseconds, which corresponds to 14 minutes. 14 minutes is so small compared to DAY_IN_MILLIS (a day). There for you get "in 0 days". 
If you want it to produce "in 14 mins", just change DAY_IN_MILLIS to MIN_IN_MILLIS.

Comment: I want to get "today"! Not "in 0 days" or  "in 14 mins"

Answer (score 0):

I came here for an alternative but I can't find perfect rather than my code.
So I shared here any improvements are welcome.

```
public String getCreatedAtRelative() {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
    CharSequence relative = null;
    try {
        relative = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(df.parse(createdAt).getTime(), new Date().getTime(),
                0L, DateUtils.FORMAT_ABBREV_ALL);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Log.e("Parse Exception adapter", "created at", e);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (null == relative) {
        return createdAt;
    } else {
        return relative.toString().replace(".", " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

for Android you can use most simple way with [Joda-Time-Android](https://github.com/dlew/joda-time-android) library:

```
Date yourTime = new Date();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(yourTime); //or simple DateTime.now()
final String result = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(getContext(), dateTime);
```

Comment: Example from TinTran?

Answer (score -2):

So your computation is based on milliseconds unit, then you format the result with SimpleDateFormat.

For this, you can easily use SimpleDateFormat formatter like this :

```
Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM yyyy");
String strDate = formatter.format(date);
```

So your computation should be based on milliseconds unit, then you format the result with SimpleDateFormat.

The pattern ("EEEE dd MMMM yyyy") allows you to get a date format like Monday, 04 February 2013.

You can change the pattern as you like : "EEEE dd/MM/yy", ...

Comment: That won't give me *relative* dates though will it? I want dates like `today` and `in two days`

Answer (score -2):

long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

DateUtils.getRelativeDateTimeString(mContext, now), DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS, DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS, 0)

[a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQZni.jpg)!